# Connecting to localhost remotely using Static IP

Tags: localhost, static-ip

I have a multi user app running on Oracle VM Virtual Box on Windows 7 machine. After starting the VirtualBox, i access it using localhost:8080 on the same machine and by using :8080 from other machines on the LAN.

I now want to access this app via internet from remote locations using static IP which i have leased from the ISP provider.

How do i configure my system to accept connection using fixed static IP from my other LAN machines or any other machine via internet?

Answer (score 1):

You need a router with "port forwarding" feature to forward the inbound connections to "static ip:port number" to "local ip:8080".

Comment: you mean every time the server machine is restarted, the port forwarding has to to be edited to the new auto assigned "localip:8080"?

Comment: If you can't have fixed IP address assigned to VM, yes.

Comment: Thanks, got "staticip:port" working but only over LAN. Still not able to access from internet. Tried pinging the static ip externally but it timed out. what to do?

Comment: Check your firewall, router, ... settings. Use TRACERT command because PING is not a reliable troubleshooting tool.